# Using Amazon S3+Cloudfront to serve images, etc - but how do I backup that data elsewhere?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 + Cloudfront quite seamlessly to store our site's images and other files. Therefore, those items are not on the web server.

I know how to backup things **to** Amazon S3, but what if I need to backup the **contents** of S3 to somewhere else, like back to the web server, for example.

I'm asking because if S3 crashes, the site would lose all it's files!

Is there are way to automate backup from S3 > web server via FTP, for example?

Comment: This isn't really a Craft-specific question... We'll migrate it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use the Amazon CLI tools and shell scripts for this:
https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

It's quite easy to use that to sync a bucket, or part of a bucket, down to a local drive.